# Using Wrap widget with text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, word-wrap

I'm trying to replicate this design.

[image]

```
SizedBox(
  width: 330.w,
  child: Wrap(
    children: [
      Transform.scale(
        scale: 1.3,
        child: Checkbox(
          value: false,
          side: const BorderSide(width: 1),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.r),
          ),
          onChanged: (bool? value) {},
        ),
      ),
      const Text('Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ...'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Since I want the text to wrap and flow downward, I used the `Wrap` widget. But the `Text` widget does not start from the same level as the checkbox. It looks like this.

[image]

Is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `RichText`, `WidgetSpan` and `TextSpan`

There is a code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        child: Checkbox(
                          value: false,
                          side: const BorderSide(width: 1),
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {},
                        )),
                  ),
                  const TextSpan(
                    text:
                        " Nullam quis risus get urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Done ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

It will be like [image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Strangely it didn't quite turn out to be how you're seeing for me. [This](https://i.imgur.com/fMU8a6v.png) is what I see. The layout is a bit off. I tested it in a fresh Flutter project so I have no other widgets either.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use `SizedBox` to remove `Checkbox` default padding

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to tweak it a bit to suit my design and get it working. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: It was nothing. It nice design, it really give me some idea

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the same design, but the code is quite simple:

```
CheckboxListTile(
    title: const Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."),
    value: false,
    onChanged: (newValue) { },
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
)
```

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not know about the `CheckboxListTile`. That is indeed handy. Although in my case, I have to stick to the design unfortunately. I managed to get it done with Sam Chen's answer. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you could indent your initial line of text with some spaces then use the STACK widget to layer the checkbox on top of your text widget, STACK allows positioning also